# How to solve the eigenvector equation using an inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a Matrix

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 1\\6 & 3\end{bmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues are

$$(A-\lambda I)x=0$$ $$det(A- \lambda I)= (-2-\lambda)(3-\lambda) - 6=0$$ $$\lambda^2 - \lambda -12=0$$ $$\lambda=-3,4$$

The eigenvectors should then be found by using the equation $$Ax=\lambda x$$
I have tried solving this by multiplying both sides by the inverse of $A$ $$A^{-1}Ax=A^{-1}\lambda x$$ However that just leads me to
$$x=A^{-1}\lambda x$$
I am unsure how to proceed in finding the eigenvector $x$ by this method, is this even possible or am I missing something crucial?

Comment: Multiplying with $A^{-1}$ will lead you to $$x = \lambda \ A^{-1} x$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\lambda = 4$, the equation $(A-\lambda I)x = 0$ becomes $$\left(\begin{bmatrix}-2&1\\6&3\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}4&0\\0&4\end{bmatrix}\right)\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$ $$\begin{bmatrix}-6&1\\6&-1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$ $$ \begin{bmatrix}-6x_1+x_2\\6x_1-x_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$ Can you find a solution to this equation? Finding the eigenvector for $\lambda = -3$ is similar.

Comment: Is there not a way to isolate $x$ from the  $x=A^{−1}λx$?

Comment: @Filthyscrub That's equivalent to finding an eigenvalue-$\lambda^{-1}$ eigenvector of $A^{-1}$, so only works if $A^{-1}$'s eigenvectors are easier to find than $A$'s.